# Why all array elments were intilized to 0 even If we hardly assign value to first few elements

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int b[100] = {0};
    int c[100] = {1, 200};

    printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], a[50], a[99]);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", b[0], b[50], b[99]);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", c[0], c[1], c[99]);

    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

[vnathan.VNATHAN-L430] ➤ ./a.exe

1629978992 1767859565

0 0 0

1 200 0

---

If none of the array elements were initialized then we have some junk value (a[]) where as if we declare one element (b[]) or first few elements (c[]) then remaining elements in the array were assigned to 0. Why is it so? I expect uninitialized elements to have junk value as array a[].

Comment: That's just the rules of C. Initialize one, initialize all. (Although there is an exception for initializing a char array from a string literal).

Comment: btw static local variables are initialized to zeros, even if no explicit initialization is done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the С Standard

> 21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration

```
If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
explicitly, then:
— if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
— if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
— if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
— if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
```

So for this definition

```
int b[100] = {0};
```

the first element is initialized explicitly by 0 and all other elements are initialized implicitly the same way as objects with the static storage duration that is with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

That is the concept of C language.

But there is a concept called **designated initialization**.

This will be useful for your for further understanding.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html